# DevTool error for FB JS SDK

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, sdk

I am trying to implement Facebook JS SDK login in my CodeIgniter app.

Loading page for couple of time I get this statement in console:

```
Service Worker termination by a timeout timer was canceled because DevTools is attached.
```

It isnt error, It is displayed in blue color.
When I try to call `FB.login()` I get this error

```
FB.login() called before FB.init().
```

The code is copied from facebook developers page.

After couple of minutes the blue text is not there. Couple reloads - again.

Comment: So that error about FB.login being called too early only occurs when you get the other blue message as well?

Comment: Can you show more code relevant to the FB error? First part in my opinion is not related to the second, but it is hard to tell without seeing the script which triggers error.

Comment: I have to apologize - the error is not related to blue message. However I still get (sometimes) blue message and do not know what it is

Comment: As the message says, you seem to be using Service Worker somewhere in your JS scripts. As long as you have developer tools opened, the worker won't terminate itself, most probably to ease development/debugging of such worker. [link to Chromium issue introducing this message](https://codereview.chromium.org/2197833003)

Comment: A bit nitpicking, but... can you edit main question and maybe the title to clarify what answer are you expecting? I've read it once more and I think that for someone who reads it for the first time and doesn't look in comments it could be unclear what exactly do you want to know.